# CSS opacity - background colour

Tags: css, opacity

I'm trying to get a black div's opacity to be .5 but the content of the div (h3 tag) to be opactiy 1. So the white text is still white, with it's opacity not changed/untouched.

```
<div style="background-color:red;">
<div style="width:470px;color:white;margin-top:170px;">
<div style="background-color:black;opacity:0.5;">
<h3 style="color:white;opacity:1;">Heading </h3><p>tagline here</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpnxW/)

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use rgba instead if you have no worries about supporting older versions of IE:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `rgba` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fpnxW/1/)

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
```

( *and don't use inline CSS* )

Comment: This maybe a given - but surely using RGBA like that is using inline CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Opacity applies down to child elements. As @MattCain suggests use RGBA on the DIV Background Color to get around this.

```
<div style="background-color:red;">
<div style="width:470px;color:white;margin-top:170px;">
<div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
<h3 style="color:white;opacity:1;">Heading </h3><p>tagline here</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```